# Mysql, timestamp and find extreme values

Tags: mysql, timestamp, max, min, points

Is it possible in mysql to find extremes values
I have table with columns (timestamp, value) and I have to detect when values started to increased and decreased and notice that value.

I.e with this datas

```
2015-05-14 04:40:00, 1000
2015-05-14 05:20:00, 2000
2015-05-14 08:00:00, 2500
2015-05-14 08:20:00, 500
2015-05-14 09:10:00, 700
2015-05-14 10:20:00, 700
2015-05-14 11:40:00, 1300
2015-05-14 12:10:00, 1800
2015-05-14 12:40:00, 2700
2015-05-14 13:20:00, 3500
2015-05-14 14:10:00, 500
2015-05-14 14:30:00, 700
2015-05-14 14:50:00, 1000
```

I need to find 2015-05-14 08:00:00, 2500 as max and

```
2015-05-14 08:20:00, 500 as min and second point
2015-05-14 13:20:00, 3500 as max
2015-05-14 14:10:00, 500 as min
```

I want to find only extreme values so I need to find only rising and trailing edge.

Data are represented in that way http://fastwork.pl/karol/wykres_extrema.png

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `MIN` and `MAX`

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE value = (SELECT MIN(value)
               FROM yourTable);
```

And it works the same for `MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

Not full answer.
But for selecting only growing values you can use:

```
SELECT t2.val
FROM `test` t1
JOIN `test` t2 ON ( t1.id = t2.id -1
AND t1.val < t2.val )
```

You need to add id primary autoincrement field

Now you need to find hole in this data
https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+holes